# How to connect to machine ip address & port via grails app

Tags: java, apache, grails, macos

I'm running MacOS 10.6 with the default settings for my machine with Internet Sharing turned on.

What needs to be configured to allow access to my machine's grails/jetty instance on a specific port?

I can do 'http://localhost/' as well as 'http://192.x.x.x/' but if I were to set my grails app to run on a specific port, I can't access it with: 'http://192.x.x.x:8081/'.

The browser can't establish a connection with this address from my own machine and I know that I need to establish an accessible port in some config file.

I used to be able to do this prior to an upgrade from the last version of the OS but it's been so long I don't remember what I did the last time.

NOTE: I can use 'grails run-app -Dserver.port=' to specify a port number for jetty to run my grails application but that still doesn't allow my machine to be accessible by ip address & port number.

Answer (score 1):

```
grails run-app -Dserver.port=<port number>
```

**run-app** Runs a grails app using the default Jetty container. The default http port is 8080. This can be customised by appending -Dserver.port= to the command line

See [the grails website](http://grails.org/Command+Line) for more details.

Comment: this has switched to tomcat container by default (i thought starting with 1.1 even), but -Dserver.port will work.  

I thought his question has to do more with MacOS issues than grails though.